# AWS Amplify: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin Unable to decode configuration

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Go easy on me please. I'm not familiar with Swift and AWS. I'm trying to use AWS Authentication for user login. Using AWSCognitoAuthPlugin, I get this error:

```
An error occurred setting up Amplify: PluginError: Unable to decode configuration
Recovery suggestion: Make sure the plugin configuration is JSONValue
```

What I have on my Swift file is very generic, following the AWS guide to get set up. I have no UI for the login as of now. I'm seeing the error via log.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Amplify
import AWSAPIPlugin
import AWSDataStorePlugin
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        do {
            Amplify.Logging.logLevel = .verbose
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Amplify configured with auth plugin")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred setting up Amplify: \(error)")
        }
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct MyAmplifyAppApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not using cocoa pods because that causes the import statement for amplify to not work. I'm following this guide from AWS:
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/ios#install-amplify-libraries

Stuck at **Initialize Amplify Auth** section last step.

Comment: have you found any solution for this? I am also stuck on this since few days.

Comment: Nope :( I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: I found the solution I am adding my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also facing same error for few days, you just have added basic files to the project and now you need to define user pools for Amplify to add more data to both config files. You need to run these commands it will fix this issue. Please make sure you are in directory of your project.

```
amplify init // It will make sure you have basic setup added
amplify add auth // It will add auth data and user pools to config files
amplify push // It will push all the setup to amplify cloud
```

Hope it will fix this issue :)

Comment: Haven't looked at it yet. I'll try it out soon.